# Finding the minimum waste using Greedy gives incorrect output

Tags: java, greedy, minimize

I am trying to solve the following problem using Greedy algorithm but I am not getting the correct output.

Here is the problem: 
[image: Problem]

**Here is a sample input:** 
20 7
10 4 6 7 6 9 4

**Here is the model output:** 
217

**My output is:** 
343
My algorithm with as a snippet of a java code is here:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Elevate {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(new FileReader("elevate.in"));
        int N, M, Weights, waste;
        M = cin.nextInt();
        N = cin.nextInt(); 
        ArrayList<Integer> wieghts = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> WT = new ArrayList<>();
        int numCase =1; 
        while(N != 0 && M != 0){
            Weights = M;
            waste = 0; 
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                wieghts.add(cin.nextInt());
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < N; ) {
                if(wieghts.get(i) <= Weights){
                   Weights -= wieghts.get(i); 
                   i++;
                }
                else{
                    //we cannot fit more people 
                    //Start again 

                    WT.add(Weights);
                    Weights = M;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < WT.size(); i++) {
                waste+= (WT.get(i) * WT.get(i) * WT.get(i));
            }

            System.out.println(numCase +": "+waste);
            M = cin.nextInt();
            N = cin.nextInt(); 
            wieghts.clear();
            WT.clear();
            numCase++;
        }

    }

}
```

Is Greedy a bad choice? the passengers has to travel in the same order of arrival, so I'm kinda doing a max fit ..

**Edit**
Greedy indeed is bad choice, DP should solve the problem.

Comment: Is `217` your entire output?

Comment: No this is the model answer my output is: 343

Comment: Hmm, the problem statement indicates the output should be in the form `casenumber, TW` so it shouldn't be just a number.

Comment: "Is Greedy a bad choice?" - I'd say yes because the result TW is the sum of all individual WF^3. Let's assume you get only 2 WF - one small and one big can be worse than 2 almost equal ones (let's say we have a total TF of 4, then 1^3+3^3 = 28 while 2^3+2^3 = 16). I'd say that it should be possible to calculate the average WF from the total weights and the maximum capacity. Then you'd want to aim each WF to be as close to that average as possible.

Comment: That's not issue (this can be solved with a simple counter). I added the full code with this solved. The main problem is either my algorithm is incorrect or the sample output is incorrect

Comment: @Thomas lets take the sample input case, we will have 3 journeys. The waste of the first is 0 (taking 10, 4, 6), the waste of the second is 7 (taking 7, 6), the last journey is not considered. So can we get the 217 :/

Comment: @Thomas I got it now, thanks!!!